# Won't able to change the size of the array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to call the function on the click of the value selected in spinner(DropDownBox in java). As spinner take 1 value default it display the data but(It's fetching the data from the databsae) when i am selecting the other value the size of my array was the same as the value which selected default.The size of my array won't change.Any suggestion or help appreciated. Thanks in advance
{This is my edited code][1](http://pastebin.com/AE8BzMaV)

Comment: List?? Didn't get u.ArrayList???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array size cannot change! You can use ArrayList instead and then convert back to array if necessary

Comment: But how to convert arraylist into array den. And i have call array when function calls. The function which retrive the rows. The array size is dynamic. Still The size won't change after once get the value???

Comment: int size=yourArrayList.size();
String[] array=new String[qty];
yourArrayList.toArray(array);

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are fixed size by definition. You probably want to use `ArrayList<Type>()`.

See [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and this [example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/how-to-use-generic-arraylist.html).

BTW, looking at your code, I suggest you use `String.split()` instead of `StringTokenizer`. It's much simpler.